# clean-up PhoneApplicationPage

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

i was about cleaning & speeding up my .xaml pages, but i'm not sure what's really needed and important of this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480">
```

already removed things i knew i can remove without complications.

Im woundering what these parts are for:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480">
```

thanks!

Comment: It's going to totally depend on what's on the page as to what you can remove.

Comment: could you please explain what the five marked-out expressions are for? then i can decide of i need them or not .thanks

Comment: Side note: you could use Resharper, it will point out which namespaces aren't used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

Default namespaces, must be maintained!

> xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

Needed for control and resource naming, must be maintained!

> xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
>   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>   mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480">

Blend related tags, you can remove this if you're not using blend!